# Apache VirtualHost redirection from different subdomains

Tags: apache

I have a DO droplet (Ubuntu 18.04) on which I want to host two sites. Let's say the droplet has an IP of 101.1.1.1. Now I want the sites to be pointed from another server (with different IP, let's say 104.1.1.1.) subdomain. Let's say siteone.example.org and sitetwo.example.org. So I follow the guides and set my Apache VirtualHost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
    ServerName siteone.example.org
    ServerAlias www.siteone.example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/siteone/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/siteone/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

However, when I press siteone.example.org in my browser I get no response. I've set A name in both to point ends to point to 101.1.1.1. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 2 web sites on the same machine, each with an IP address?  So:

- configure both IP on your system
- Set both IP:80 in Listen
- Configure one VirtualHost per IP / domain

Like so:

```
Listen *.80

<VirtualHost 101.1.1.1:80>
    ServerName siteone.example.org
    ServerAlias www.siteone.example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster.example.org

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/siteone/public/html"
    <Directory /var/www/siteone/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/siteone_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/siteone_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 104.1.1.1:80>
    ServerName sitetwo.example.org
    ServerAlias www.sitetwo.example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster.example.org

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/sitetwo/public/html"
    <Directory /var/www/sitetwo/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/siteotwo_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitetwo_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

In your DNS, configure:

- 101.1.1.1    siteone.example.org    www.siteone.example.org
- 104.1.1.1    sitetwo.example.org    www.sitetwo.example.org